# SSL verification issues

Tags: php

as requested by someone helping me yesterday I've put this in a new post. The issue I am having is that a host site went SSL and now my code will no longer pull the data it needs from the site, so I either need to get SSL working (which it doesn't verify for some reason) or disable the verification of SSL. My original code is here:

```
<?php

require_once("/home4/ahevent2/public_html/jumi_src/event_logs/admin_functions.php");
require_once("/home4/ahevent2/public_html/jumi_src/event_logs/cURL.php");

if (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"]) && !isset($_POST["event_type"]))
{
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password  = $_POST["password"];
  $url = "https://bbs.hitechcreations.com/cms/cmlogs.php";
  $f1 = 'loginid'; // Name of field1(ON THE WEBSITE YOU'RE TRYING TO LOGIN ON!)
  $f2 = 'password'; // Name of field2(ON THE WEBSITE YOU'RE TRYING TO LOGIN ON!)
  $v1 = $username; // Value of field1(FROM THE WEBSITE YOU'RE TRYING TO LOGIN FROM!)
  $v2 = $password; // Value of field2(FROM THE WEBSITE YOU'RE TRYING TO LOGIN FROM!)
  //$find = 'Welcome to your account'; // String to search for in the page you've logged in on
  $postchars = http_build_query( array($f1 => $v1, $f2 => $v2) );

  $stream = stream_context_create( array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' =>  htmlspecialchars_decode( $postchars ) ) ) ); // Creates an array of the sourcecode, and inputs the values of the field1 and field2

$fh = file_get_contents($url, false, $stream);  //for troubleshooting.

var_dump($fh);
//REALLY NEEDS A HANDLER FOR WHEN $FH DOESN"T COME BACK FOR SOME REASON.


//printf("Login wasn't completed. No file was retreived. Please check your password at the htc CM login page to verify that it's good. If it is there is a systme issue. Please let Nefarious know.");


 //FOR TROUBLESHOOTING
//  printf("<textarea rows='100' cols='100'>");
//  printf($fh);
//  printf("</textarea>");



//getting the dropdown box returned from THC to select a scenario to upload
        $a = strpos($fh, "<select name"); 
        $b = strpos($fh, "</SELECT>");     
        $c = strlen($fh) - $b;  
        $e = substr($fh, $a, -$c); 




//  printf("<textarea rows='100' cols='100'>");
//  printf($e);
//  printf("</textarea>");

                //THE CM SELECTION FORM
                //------------------------------------------
                printf("<center><p class = 'redtitle'>Aces High Events Headquarters Admin: Upload Logs</p></center>");
                printf("<td>Which log to use? </td>");
                printf("<form method='POST' action='' name='form'>");
                printf($e);
                printf("</SELECT>");
                printf("<hr size='2' width='80%'>");
                                printf("<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='2000000'>");
                printf("<table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' border='0'>");
                printf("<tr>");
```

A user (maio290) was helping me and provided me with this cURL code:

```
<?PHP
function POST($url,$data,$headers, $type)
{
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    if($type === 1)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    }
    else
    {
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    $output = curl_exec ($ch);
    $posturl = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $cURLinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return array(
        "output" => $output,
        "posturl" => $posturl,
        "httpcode" => $httpCode,
        "diagnostics" => $cURLinfo
    );
}
?>
```

If I utilize this code he provided me for the top part of my script:

```
require_once("/home4/ahevent2/public_html/jumi_src/event_logs/admin_functions.php");
require_once("/home4/ahevent2/public_html/jumi_src/event_logs/cURL.php");

if (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"]) && !isset($_POST["event_type"]))
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password  = $_POST["password"];
    $url = "https://bbs.hitechcreations.com/cms/cmlogs.php";  
    $postchars = array(
            "loginid" => $username,
            "password" => $password
        );
    $headers = array("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    $postResponse = POST($url,$postchars ,$headers,1);
    $fh = $postResponse['output'];

//getting the dropdown box returned from THC to select a scenario to upload
        $a = strpos($fh, "<select name"); 
        $b = strpos($fh, "</SELECT>");     
        $c = strlen($fh) - $b;  
        $e = substr($fh, $a, -$c);
```

Now, this code produces this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvBNJ.png
This is progress as it allows the dropdown that I need to appear on my site. The issue is, the code is pulling the entire host site rather than just the dropdown that I need (here is an image of the host site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mufFA.png ). Once a user selects something from the dropdown and fills out the rest of the fields and clicks Upload, the rest of the original code is set to parse the information and upload it to our  MYSQL database. The dropdown is supposed to appear next to "Which log to use?" (see this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rULMZ.png )

My question is, what changes would be needed to only pull that dropdown, or pull it correctly? The original code is set to do so, but for some reason will not pull it due to SSL verification issues. I have no problems disabling the verification as this is not sensitive data, but every attempt I've made to disable it has not worked.

Comment: Can you please reduce the code to the relevant parts where you get the error? I don't believe anyone would like to go through hundreds of lines of code. Read about creating a [mcve]

Comment: Apologies, I have edited out most of the irrelevant stuff. I was told to post all of it. :)

Comment: Setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false is a very bad thing to do, and IIRC it doesn't even work in modern versions of PHP. Use a proper certificate. They're free these days.

Comment: The certificate *is* valid. How else would it work on browsers ? Check your local CA certificates.

Comment: @msg The host site has a valid cert when I look at an SSL checker site. I've downloaded a CA Cert bundle that does include Comodo (which is the cert they have) and made necessary changes to the php.ini file, but it doesn't make any difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the following options to the POST method

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , 2);
```

Comment: I've added these to my curl.php file but it does not make any difference when refreshing the site. If I add it directly into my base code, it brings up the entire login screen of the link we're trying to access. (reference: https://i.imgur.com/iaHHHe6.png )